# Spray, Akka and Apache Kafka Producer

Tags: akka, apache-kafka, spray

I am creating a simple REST-Api with Spray/Akka to receive a json message and pass it to a Apache Kafka producer. The Apache Kafka producer is a non-blocking API to send messages to the Kafka message broker and is thread-safe (should be shared by all threads).

My basic architecture is the following (pseudo code) in the routing trait

```
 val myKafkaProducerActor = system.actorOf(Props[KafkaProducerActor])

 val route = {
  path("message") {
  get {
    entity(as[String]) { message =>
        myKafkaProducerActor ! message
  }
  }
  }
```

That is, I use always one single actor (myKafkaProducerActor) to forward the message, since that actor only contains very minimal checks (check if is a json document at all) and hand it over immediately to the non-blocking message producer api.

My concern is now:

- Does it make sense at all to forward the message to a separate actor (the kafka producer is non-blocking, I have only separated it due to the validity checks, which are cheap currently, although).
- How does the default akka message reliability affect spray (at most once delivery). Is it only theoretical, since the message is forwarded on the same jvm ? Is it better to not use any followup actors at all and accept a small performance penalty but have a greater reliability ?

Thanks.